# .Less file extension not compiled

Tags: css, less, host

It works great, but unfortunately my web host does not support .less file extensions...
When I enter example.com/styles.less gives an error.

**Error:**

> The page cannot be found
>        The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

When I upload another hosting everything is okay...

**My include:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change the extension to `.css` (or something else that your webhost allows) and it still should work.  To the best of  my knowledge, less.js is just looking at `rel="stylesheet/less"`.

This seems to be consistent with the documentation: http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage